# Atlas by Vagrant... what happen with Vagrant Cloud?

Tags: cloud, vagrant, atlas

With the introduction of `Atlas` by `Vagrant`, `Hashicorp` will stop supporting `Vagrant Cloud`. This means that there will be no way to download Vagrant Boxes as was done in Vagrant Cloud? It will become a paid service?

Comment: I have no information at all about that, but I think both Atlas & VagrantCloud will still work in parallel: currently the vagrantcloud.com redirect to the Atlas homepage, but the box list still exists [here](https://vagrantcloud.com/boxes/search). The `vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64` still works. Also, the Vagrant's doc have been [updated](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html) to add the interaction between Vagrant & Atlas. I'm looking for more information about this but can't find anything :/

Comment: Thanks for the information Diego. I’m aware that currently the service is still up and running (and free). I receive an email from Hashicorp with the announcement and this line capture my whole attention: "This means all your existing Vagrant Cloud features will be free until Atlas exits the tech preview sometime early next year." My concern is because right now I’m using Vagrant Cloud more and more in my projects and I want to be prepare if the service is going to be transformed in a pay as a service product.

Comment: On currently free feature is the free indexing of "self-hosted" box versions (ones hosted on third party websites, but still available with vagrant tools), but it isn't yet clear if that option may become paid-only in the future :-/

Comment: Open source world is not totally free any more. No one will give up the chance to be a millionaire or even billionaire.

Answer (score 0):

From the atlas site, there will be some paid features, but things that were free of charge in vagrant cloud will remain so.

"As a reminder, any paid plans you were on have been cancelled, but all features are now free in the Atlas tech preview. You'll hear more about pricing at the end of the preview. Features that were free in Vagrant Cloud will stay free – potentially more free features, but not less."

quote from 
https://atlas.hashicorp.com/development
last paragraph of section: Transitioning from Vagrant Cloud